# ) expected error in stack program

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stack, turbo-c

this is my code...i am getting that error at 'void push(int item, STACK *S)'.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#define STACK_SIZE 5

struct stack
{
int arr[STACK_SIZE];
int top;
};


type def struct stack,STACK;
void push(int item, STACK *S)
{
if(S->top==STACK_SIZE-1)
{
    printf("stack overflow\n");
    return;
}
S->top++;
S->arr[S->top]=item;
  } 

  void pop(STACK *S)
{
int item;
if(S->top==-1)
{
    printf("stack overflow\n");
    return;
}

printf("deleted element is %d \n ",S->arr[S->top--]);
   }

 void display(STACK *S)
 {
int i;
if(S->top==-1)
{
    printf("stack underflow\n");
    return;
}

printf("the contest of the stack \n");
for(i=s->top;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("%d\n",S->arr[i]);
}
    } 


   void main()
   {
int item,ch;
STACK S;
clrsacr();
S.to=-1;
for(;;)
{
    printf("1:push\n 2:pop\n 3:display\n 4:exit\n");
    printf("enter the choice\n");
    scanf("%d",ch);

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: printf("enter the item to be inserted\n");
            scanf("%d",&item);
            push(item,&S);
            break;

        case 2: pop(&s);
            break;

        case 3: display(&S);
            break;

        default: exit(0);
    }
}
getch();
    }
```

in this i'm getting another error...declaration terminated incorrectly at "type def struct stack,STACK;'. i got this error while compiling this program in turbo c. i am a bit new to stacks.

Comment: Did you read any `C` program book before?

Comment: i am good with C...just learning stack now...

Comment: `typedef` not `type def` and remove `,`

Comment: post real code. you have error before the mentioned line.

Comment: Also, if you're just learning C, I would strongly recommend that you learn it using a modern compiler. Turbo C is incredibly old - depending on what version you're using, it was released between 1987 and 1992. A lot of things have changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type def struct stack,STACK;
    ^ typedef is a keyword not type def
```

Use:-

`typedef struct stack STACK;`

Comment: i removed space still getting same error..

Comment: @user3280448 comma too, also few other errors too

Comment: got it...thanks...can u explain a bit..

Comment: @user3280448 just refer the syntax for use of typedef, there's nothing to explain over here. Fix couple of type and you'll be good to go. Also don't use decade old compilers

Answer (score 1):

Remove `space` and `,` in typedef

change to

```
typedef struct stack STACK;
```

instead of

```
type def struct stack,STACK;
```

Also you can typedef your structure as

```
typedef struct stack
{
    int arr[STACK_SIZE];
    int top;
}STACK;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `type def struct stack,STACK;` to `typedef struct stack STACK;`

Also change

`S.to = -1 ;`

to

`S.top= -1 ;`

and its  `clrscr();` instead of `clrsacr();`